# Wrap plot data in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm developing a visualization tool for a medical pressure sensor, and i need to keep my x axis fixed between 0 and 20 sec, and when the Y data "overflows" that value, just override the last value with the new one, like the EKG diagram does. I can currently plot the new data,but the old values when I override stay there.
This is a plot of the first iteration of the data reading:
[image]

As you can see, as I start plotting the "new" data, the old values keep staying in the way, producing this effect:
[image]

I need to draw only the updated data while keeping the old curves but overriding when new data comes in, like this:
[image]

Just like that image but without clearing the curves in function of time.

This is my current code:

```
  import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import time
plt.style.use('ggplot')

lastmillis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))

class Plot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=1)
        self.line.set_data([], [])
        self.x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
        self.y = np.empty(shape=(1000,))
        self.state = 0
        return
    def animate(self,i):
        if i >= self.x.size:
            i = i % self.x.size
            if self.state == 1:
                self.state = 0
            elif self.state == 0:
                self.state = 1

        print(i,",",self.x.size)
        if self.state == 0:
            self.y[i] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (0.01 * i))
        else:
            self.y[i] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * (0.01 * i))

        self.line.set_data(self.x, self.y)
        return self.line,

plot = Plot()
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, plot.animate,
                                interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Any help or hint for doing this correctly?
Thank you in advance

Comment: @anon Thank you, that was my problem, did not realise that i was the frame number and kept increasing, i added a check and now its working. Thank you!